# How many solutions for an equation using generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> How many solutions the equation $x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = m$ for $m\in\Bbb{N}, x_{1,3}\in \Bbb{N_{even}}, x_2\in\Bbb{N}$ ?
>
> Show that $i\in\Bbb{N}$, $2i$ and $2i+1$ has the same amount of solutions.

**My Work -**

So we can define $x_i$ as - $x_{1,3} = 1+x^2 +x^4...$ and $x^2 = 1+x+x^2+x^3+...$ and define our generating function $f$ as -

$f(x) = \lambda x\in\Bbb{R}. x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3 \,\, \Rightarrow$ $f(x) =  \lambda x\in\Bbb{R}. (1+x^2+x^4+...)^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+..)$

$f(x) = \lambda x\in\Bbb{R}. \dfrac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x} \Rightarrow $ $f(x) = \lambda x\in\Bbb{R}.\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

$\iff f(x) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2} x^n \cdot \Big(\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty(-1)^k\cdot x^n\Big)^2$ $\iff f(x) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2} x^n \cdot \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$

So we want to find the coefficient of $m$, which if i am right is $\binom{m+2}{2} + 1$ for $m\in\Bbb{N_{even}}$ and $\binom{m+2}{2}$ for $m\in\Bbb{N_{odd}}$ ? Is everything legit ? I think i miss something because $\binom{m+2}{2}$ $\not=$
$\binom{m+2}{2} +1$ (?)

Comment: $\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^k \cdot x^n \right)^2 \ne \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$.

Comment: Ok. still couldn't make a good progress, any hints?

Comment: I would expand $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \cdot \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ using partial fractions.  And then, for example, $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1 - (-x))^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{n+1}{1} x^n$.

Comment: I am not sure they can expand.. or can they ? How can i express $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}$?

Comment: By "partial fraction expansion" I mean $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3 (1+x)^2} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{C}{(1-x)^3} + \frac{D}{1+x} + \frac{E}{(1+x)^2}$ for some constants $A,B,C,D,E$.

Comment: Try $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2} \frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{4(1 - x)^3} + \frac{1}{4(1 - x)^2}+\frac{3}{16(1-x)} +  \frac{1}{8(1+x)^2} + \frac{3}{16(1+x)}$

Comment: Hmm, in this problem there's a bit of a shortcut for the last part if you're clever: note that $(1-x) f(x)$ is an even function, so its coefficients are zero for odd exponents.  That implies that if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, then $a_{2i+1} - a_{2i} = 0$ for each $i$.

Comment: @rtybase great.. and how can i expand $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ ..?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you very much

Comment: @YarivLevy I already showed how to expand $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ in a previous comment.